# Should we have a "spoilers" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should our policiy be regarding spoilers?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policiy-be-regarding-spoilers)

I can see some benefits of having it. For example, if I see a question related to an anime I'm watching now, I might open it to see if I can answer. If there are spoilers inside

> (even properly formatted like this)

then the worst that will happen is me losing some time opening the question. Of course, if the spoilers are not properly formatted (even if they are minor) that may be pretty disappointing.

Having the "spoilers" tag will help to prevent such situations since people that don't want spoilers will not open the questions in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. [spoiler](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) is a meta tag. It doesn't describe the content of the question, but the question itself. It didn't indicate what the question is about, it indicates what might be inside.

Comment: Here is what is meant by a "meta tag" — http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: In addition to being a meta tag, the spoiler tag is also *completely* useless. Nearly every question is going to have spoilers of some kind, and the tag alone isn't enough to inform users what the spoiler is for. All it does it take up valuable tag space.

Answer (score 2):

I see your reasoning but I think I'll vote against.

The fact is that tags are meant to classify the question's content (this is also why you don't apply tags based on answers), while the [spoiler](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag would classify the question "type".

Also other sites made this decision, I suggest you look at this question: [Spoiler alert: [spoiler] dies](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/20633).