# Should we really allow spoilers in the title?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

By nature, this site is where we ask questions from both manga and anime. However %90 of the time, anime is behind the manga so asking a question from the manga can be considered as a spoiler for anime-only people.

A small example would be:

> Why the character X is doing Y?

The problem is, in the anime we still don't know X and now we are sure that X will do Y.

Now there are many discussions about this I am aware but none of them is conclusive. Some are against it, some say it's fine. Others say we should try to do it without spoilers but if we can't then it's fine. Is it really? Let's imagine a scenario where a member of the community checks the questions daily. Then bang, he sees a spoiler from a show he is watching. He clearly did nothing wrong but the person who is seeking an answer didn't either.

Some examples from other discussions:

[What should our policy be regarding spoilers?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policy-be-regarding-spoilers)

[Should we have a “spoilers” tag?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/should-we-have-a-spoilers-tag)

[What do we do with questions which are spoiler by nature?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-do-we-do-with-questions-which-are-spoiler-by-nature)

[Should this question have avoided spoilers in the title or not?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/should-this-question-have-avoided-spoilers-in-the-title-or-not)

Thus my proposal is as follows:

We should clearly imply that the question itself is a spoiler. An example would be like:

> [Show A - Manga Spoiler] Why the character X is doing Y?

With a standard like that, at least we can create a middle ground for both of the sides.

Comment: FYI this isn't a _sub_ reddit this is a _Q&A site_. Also when I make meta posts like this I like to link to the metas I know about so people newish to Meta know what you're talking about. It may be a good idea to link to these discussions you've mentioned.

Comment: Well, the concept of "sub of a site" is older than Reddit so I wasn't making a connection there. After all, we can't add new global features by our own and the hosting is handled by the StackExchange team. However, to make things clearer, edited accordingly and added some example questions to the post.

Comment: If you find that a title to be a bit too spoilery, you can edit the title to imply spoilers or edit out the spoilery bit. E.g., "What did X mean during Y scene in episode Z?"

Comment: Yes, we can edit it but what happens if you are the one who is spoiled.

Comment: This site isn't as popular as the movies or sci-fi stack exchanges, so this isn't as much of a concern, but I think it's also worth considering the perspective of someone on a completely different site inadvertently coming across unsolicited series spoilers in HNQ. Related discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361307/film-spoilers-are-showing-up-as-hot-network-questions) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224108/prevent-questions-with-movie-tv-shows-game-spoilers-from-appearing-in-the-hot-qu).

Answer (score 4):

The general stance I have seen so far, and been following myself regarding spoilers in titles is mentioned in the answer [What should our policy regarding spoilers be](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/1458).

> The rule I've always followed is to include spoilers in your title only if it's required for the title to be searchable, and clearly indicate what the question is about. In other words, if you can make a good title without spoilers, do so; otherwise include spoilers. **A good title is more important than spoilers**. After all, the ignore tag feature will allow users to ignore any tags in a series they wish to avoid spoilers about

I do not believe we should be avoiding spoilers, just for the sake of avoiding spoilers. We should strive for quality of our content, which in some cases will require spoilers, even in the title.

And for the people that daily check questions, and really don't want to be spoiled, can add certain tags to their ignore list, at least for the duration they do not want to be spoiled.

[image]

Comment: My initial idea was to use the tag system where if you tag a question with spoiler tag, it should hide the question automatically unless you change it via settings but that is not something we can do so I proposed this one. I don't think adding a warning would decrease the quality of the post but thanks for the input.

Comment: You mention striving for quality of content, but I'd also add that the content being _findable_ is extremely important — titles that make questions unfindable for people with the same question somewhere on the web aren't particularly useful... :)