# Should we say the episode/chapter/season in the question to help avoid spoilers (and also to possibly be clearer or more helpful)?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, title-wording

Related:

[Should this question have avoided spoilers in the title or not?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/should-this-question-have-avoided-spoilers-in-the-title-or-not-death-note-spoi)

[What should our policy be regarding spoilers?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policy-be-regarding-spoilers)

---

**Thing 1: Spoilers**

I think it's not so hard to handle spoilers in answers to questions. For example this [Psycho-Pass s1 question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28440/what-states-besides-japan-have-a-the-sibyl-system) requires s2 to answer, so you can just say

> My answer spoils s2.

> [insert answer covered in spoiler]

Similar for this [Danganronpa s1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29332/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-is-no-corpse) question.

I guess the harder issue is spoilers in questions.

Consider an anime X based on manga X. Let's say there's a question about the latest chapter of manga X but then an unwitting user assumes the question is about anime X and opens it. Then the user is spoiled.

I happen to know in other sites like reddit or myanimelist, it is extremely forbidden to put a spoiler in the title. This isn't just for anime but other for other fiction subreddits/forums and even for, like, sports or gaming subreddits/forums. **To address the aforementioned case, those sites/forums even go a step further** to have people say what exactly is their post about (the anime and if so what season/episode, the manga and if so what chapter/volume, etc)

I think we should say in the title or the beginning of the post what is being referenced. What do you think?

We could go a step further to do like:

If I have a question about the anime X but want to mention a bit of manga X, then I can take 1 of 2 approaches:

1. Approach 1: Mention at the start the question is about both anime X and manga X and thus have no need to use spoiler tag but this may discourage anime-only fans from reading my question.
2. Approach 2: Mention at the start the question is about anime X and so my little bit reference to manga X shall use spoiler tag. Thus, I don't discourage anime-only fans from reading. Something like [this Kaguya-sama s2 question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66615/why-does-nagisa-call-kaguya-1st-kaguya-sama-then-later-shinomiya-san-and-then-la), which brings up a later manga chapter but in spoiler text.

---

**Thing 2: Clearer or more helpful**

I believe this would also make it more convenient for users who might not have otherwise answered. Their 1st question about the post might be 'What episode/season was this again?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally reverse the purpose, but, **yes, questions should always mention the specific source/reference *as context* if possible, at least on the body.** (The title is sometimes too verbose for this, and not everything is a spoiler).

Source/reference is one of the most important contexts for readers/future answerers so that they can cross-check the canonical info with the premise of the question.

Avoiding spoilers is just an additional benefit since the spoiler can then be hidden  *without losing too much context* for the question to make sense, and also work both as a warning, and hopefully, as an eye-catcher. (Compare [the original](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/36258/1) to [the revision](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/36258/5))

Comment: Hahaha wow thanks Andrew. Agreeing with what I want but for reversed reasons. Lol. Happy Easter!

Comment: Andrew [in the most recent revision the last part (after 'Could anyone explain it to me?')](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/36258/5) doesn't say what exactly is being spoiled. Like for all we know it's spoiling some future thing beyond episode 11. Should it maybe? or idk...maybe it's understood to be part of episode 11 spoilers only?

Comment: That's the spoiling question up until episode 11 (what the OP has given as the context). I don't see any need to be too verbose.