# Why were the edit suggestions rejected and no other actions taken about the spoilerous title?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I refer to these 4 edit rejects that come from a Code Geass question with huge [spoilers IN THE TITLE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31889):

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70372

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70379

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70383

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70384

1. The last says

> Edit summary's are not the place for rants and unrelated suggested edits.

However, what could've been done if the edit is otherwise acceptable is to reject the edit but then make the changes anyway. Why wasn't it done? Pride? The alternative is to keep the spoilerous title [which should not be there in the 1st place](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2656).

2. They all disagree with my title edit and consequent body edits, but acknowledge the title is spoilerous. How can the mods just do nothing about the spoilerous titles?

If I search or scroll through anime SE with titles like these, then I will be regularly spoiled.

Note: See [Should this question have avoided spoilers in the title or not?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/should-this-question-have-avoided-spoilers-in-the-title-or-not)

> I strongly advocate for avoiding spoilers in titles except when they are really, genuinely, 100% necessary for the post to make any sense.

Answer (score 11):

You're really pushing the envelope here with your self employed crusade on spoilers. Your persistent efforts are presumptuous, pompous, self-serving and generally unwelcome. While you are free to express your opinion, there is a proper venue for doing so, the comments and revisions/edit summary notes are not the place to be passive aggressive on topics or policies that you find irksome. Unlike some of the other Stack Exchange sites in were you have been suspended, we've cut you a lot of slack and given you a lot more leeway. We don't expect you to be grateful for any of this.

We would like you to take a moment to take a breath and cool off a bit. Please try to be reasonable and less insistent on have things in a particular way. As much as you prefer that it be done your way, this site serves other people besides you. You should take time to listen to them and find parts where you can reach some sort of compromise.

It's up to the community to work together and find some way to make things work. If we cant, we can look at other alternatives and go from there.