# A code geass spoiler title

Tags: discussion, spoilers, specific-question

There's [this question with a Code Geass spoiler title](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31917). It is

> CC's loss of memory

How can this be made less spoilerous? I think of...

> Why did this character lose their memories?

But for me I even find

> lose memories

spoilerous. I prefer

> Why did this character forget?

Again you can [always say the real title at the start of the body](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/should-this-question-have-avoided-spoilers-in-the-title-or-not):

> Keep in mind that when you google for an answer to some anime-related question, google indexes both the title and the body of the post, so stuff is still findable even if you're somewhat roundabout in the title. While I imagine the title is granted more weight, avoiding spoilers in the title still likely does little harm. I think that the benefit of avoiding spoiling users' experience with various shows outweighs the cost of losing some descriptiveness in the titles.

Comment: If you do not want to be spoiled for specific series, I would recommend you add the tags of those series to your ignored tag list. You can do so on the main page on the right hand, right below the watched tags.

Answer (score 11):

This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Questions are supposed to be useful to future visitors, so they may to be able to better find them in the proper context. While spoilers should be likely avoided in titles, but titles devoid of information like “what did this character do after this event?” are not helpful.

Please realize that the site and them community does not exist to cater to your sole whims and demands. This like many other Stack Exchange site is a shared platform used by others. We might not agree on all points, but we work together to try to reach a consensus, rather than brute forcing policies through and not listening to the community at large.