# When to use the spoilers tag and should it be used at all

Tags: discussion

Ok, this is my personal opinion, I always thought a spoiler tag in a Q&A board about stories doesnt make sense. Why? Because anything it's a spoiler for someone who hasnt seen a segment of a story yet. Then, when to use a spoiler tag becomes completely arbitrary. But, in the case they should be use, I think there should be practical rules. Which these practical rules should be I truly don't know (since I think spoilers tags dont make sense in a Q&A board) . For example, if you want to use it for manga content (because manga it's released first than anime, and it contains spoilers) many if not most manga questions should be tagged, which again, in my opinion, it doesnt make sense because it adds you a barrier for people to make questions, but it could have some logic I suppose. Another example, use the tag when a movie is relatively new. This forbiddes you to make you certain questions which should have the spoiler in the title. For example, let's suppose a new Dragon Ball movie has a new transformation and I want to make a question about it. The very question itself would be a spoiler in this sense. This even becomes less reasonable when promotional material made by the authors include the spoiler, some people argues they don't want to see.

So, is there any practical rule for the spoilers tag? Should they be used? If there is a practical rule, shouldnt it be in the FAQ of the anime SE website?

Comment: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/1458