# Can I include anti-spoiler instructions in a question?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

E.g. "Why did X happen? Please don't include content past episode 150", *assuming* the question is answerable as such.

Here's the exact question I have in mind, which contains episode 218 & 282 spoilers for Boruto: Naruto Next Generations: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNEFA.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, *it's discouraged to prevent answers past certain chapters/episodes* because the question is not only for the asker but also for future visitors. Otherwise, if the answer is only available past that chapter, then the only possible answer is "it's explained in episode x, but spoiler!" without mentioning the detail, which is pretty much a sub-standard answer on Stack Exchange.

Instead, **suggest the answers to use spoiler blocks past certain chapters.** This will give everyone the freedom if they want to spoil themselves.

Further reading: [What should our policy be regarding spoilers?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/2516)

Comment: Thanks! Is the following OK? ---- I've not watched or read past episode X; please wrap such content in spoilers (using `!>`). "It's explained later / in ep X" also works.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon the point is, Stack Exchange always encourages having standalone answers, preferably without needing to search and read external sources to understand the answers. "It's explained later in ep X" is almost similar to "[your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/241919)" which while not as bad as a non-descriptive link-only answer, it's still a low-quality answer.

Comment: Right, I didn't word that well. I'd prefer, though it's not critical, that the episode number wasn't disclosed either, without the spoiler bubble - is that fine? New wording ------ I've not watched or read past episode X; please wrap such content in spoilers (using `!>`), including the episode number, but otherwise OK to mention "it's explained later".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon although it's not my personal preference to also hide the chapter/episode number because future visitors have to guess whether they will be spoiled or not, I think that's still a fair suggestion as the asker.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. In that case maybe it works to suggest the episode number, if stated, be with a ~10 episode uncertainty window, as personally I rather not know the exact episode an event is due.